# AJAX results in either a unexpected end of input error or an internal server error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently creating an ASP.NET MVC project, and my AJAX script is causing errors. I apologize for posting such a specific question, but I have honestly been stuck here for days.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Update/",  //this calls a method in my controller to update the database.
    data: JSON.stringify('{ "ToUpdate" : "1",  "ID" : "@variableWithinCode" }'),
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(jqXHR.status);
     alert(errorThrown);
   },
   success: function(response){
      //code here never executes as error is always thrown.
   }
});
```

My Controller currently is of type ActionResult and returns the View.  However, I have also tried returning nothing (void) and returning a JsonResult.  Neither of these changes resulted in no errors.

Please could someone push me in the right direction, my Console has no errors.  Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: JSON.stringify is rarely needed. Is @variableWithinCode supposed to be a Razor-injected value?

Comment: Yes, I've checked with the debugger and the resulting database update, and the correct value is passed through.  I tried without the JSON.stringify, just data: { "ToUpdate" : "1",  "ID" : "@variableWithinCode" }
However, this still results in a 200: Syntax: unexpected end of input error.

Comment: I'd suggest including your controller action, then, since there isn't anything in what you've shown so far that would cause that response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost always use the simpler `$.post` helper (which wraps `$.ajax`), rather than `$.ajax` directly. Here's your code, updated to use `$.post`:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Update", "Home")',
    { 
        ToUpdate : "1",  
        ID : "@variableWithinCode" 
    })
    .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(response);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

You can also use the Url helper to inject the URL into your Javascript, assuming this code is in a `<script>` tag in a view.

In response to your comment:

It sounds like you're using this code within an event handler for a "button" of some sort. If that's the case, you'll want to capture the "this" context outside the ajax call, like so:

```
$('some-selector').on('click', function(e){

    var _this = $(this);

    $.post('@Url.Action("Update", "Home")',
    { 
        ToUpdate : "1",  
        ID : "@variableWithinCode" 
    })
    .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){        

        _this.find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-down');

    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work :)  However, within my .done function, I have the line  
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-down');  
this no longer changes the glyphicon shown in the View, but the rest of the code in my .done executes.